# Conditional auto-retry in GitLab pipeline

Tags: gitlab

I'm having network issues and my Docker builds fail often with:

> ```
> Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: TLS handshake timeout
> ```

I'm wondering if it's possible to make GitLab retry automatically when that happens.

Comment: It's not exactly what you ask, but I assume you are already aware of ["retry" command](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#retry) for `.gitlab-ci.yml`. Perhaps a `retry: 5` could be a quick & dirty solution to mitigate your problem.

Comment: yea. I was thinking about some gitlab configuration.  I don't want to create messy repo because I have a messy platform :/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the local [gitlab dependency proxy](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/dependency_proxy/). Which should help with unstable connections and speed up your builds.